# Unable to load the requested file (no case sensitive)

Tags: codeigniter

I'm just starting use `CodeIgniter` and I have created a controller called `Dashboard`, inside that I have the following method:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('dashboard/home');
}
```

then I have defined inside the folder `Views` a folder called `dashboard` which have the following content:

[image]

then inside `routes.php` I have defined as default controller `dashboard`:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'dashboard';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

when I start the application I get:

> Unable to load the requested file: dashboard/home.php

that's weird because I have no upper case letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Check .htaccess file inside the root folder of project.If .htaccess file not exist create .htacess file in root folder and add this below line.

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: thanks this works, do you have found that in the official doc? I didn't find to add the .htaccess with such code

Comment: Sry i don't have a document.